# Using mclapply over a list of lists

Tags: r, parallel-processing, tidyverse, lapply

Suppose I have the below list of lists :

```
users_days_delays <- list(users, days, delays)
```

where

```
users <- list(1, 2, 3)
days <- list(1, 2, 3, 4)
delays <- list(0, 100)
```

I have the below function

```
compute_time <- function(user_day_delay){
user <- user_day_delay[[1]]
days <- user_day_delay[[2]]
delays <- user_day_delay[[3]]

time_per_user <- days+delays - 180*user

return(time_per_user)
}
```

Is there a way for me to use mclapply on the users_days_delays list of lists?

For ex. can I do :

```
time_per_users <- mclapply(users_days_delays, compute_time)
```

Thank you!

Comment: Are users, days, delays supposed to have different lengths?

Comment: `user_day_delay$1` is not valid R syntax

Comment: @Arthur, I basically want to apply the function to all triples made from users x days x delays

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(tidyverse)

compute_time <- function(user, day, delay){
  time_per_user <- day + delay - 180*user
  return(time_per_user)
}

df <- expand_grid(
  user  = c(1, 2, 3),
  day   = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
  delay = c(0, 100),
)

df$time_per_user <- pmap_dbl(df, compute_time)
print(df)
#> # A tibble: 24 x 4
#>     user   day delay time_per_user
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>         <dbl>
#>  1     1     1     0          -179
#>  2     1     1   100           -79
#>  3     1     2     0          -178
#>  4     1     2   100           -78
#>  5     1     3     0          -177
#>  6     1     3   100           -77
#>  7     1     4     0          -176
#>  8     1     4   100           -76
#>  9     2     1     0          -359
#> 10     2     1   100          -259
#> # ... with 14 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you this is a great solution @Arthur. 
However, I have to keep users, days, delays as lists. In particular, in my real example, delays is a list of matrices, and so I would want to have a different data structure than a df! Is there a way for me to keep users as a list of matrices for example?

Comment: Have you tried this approach with a list?  I think it should work.

Comment: thank you so much. I am about to accept this as the correct answer.
However, I realise this doesn't solve the problem. `pmap` does not parralellize in the sense of mclapply, where we can use multicores. @Arthur.